# 80's movie involving supernatural beings, possibly witchcraft

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror, supernatural

Decades ago I went to a double-feature and I only remember the name of the 1st movie, *[Phantasm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phantasm_(film))*. This had to be around 1979/1980 when *Phantasm* was released.

The other movie though, I can't recall the name and only saw the beginning. The scene I remember is, it's dark, maybe in Europe in some catacombs or a cathedral and a young man (tall, thin, blond, jeans and short sleeved striped shirt, I think) is following a woman. She may have been thin, short reddish/blonde hair, freckled. I believe he's following her because they made eye contact and she was playing coy, getting him to follow her.

She finally stops and he approaches her. They kiss and she may have disrobed (most likely, it *is* a 70's movie) suddenly we see her leave and he's lying there looking up, but as the camera gets close, you see his head is turned around backward.

That's about all I got. I think it was supernatural and witchcraft based, but my sister took the popcorn and said we have to leave; she didn't want to watch a "dirty" movie (I was 10, she was 15).

I've looked for years, even scrolled through every 1979/1980 horror movie listed on IMDB but nothing seemed familiar.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: What do you mean "his head is a full 180"?

Comment: @Valorum I read that as "turned back to front;" the chin is facing the spine.

Comment: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0106636/?ref_=tt_urv?

Comment: @DavidW that is correct. He is dead due to his neck breaking from his head being turned  to face behind himself. I don't recall any blood in this scene.

Comment: @Valorum that wouldn't be it the movie had to have been released by 1980.

Comment: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0083585/?

Comment: Where did you watch this? Was this in the USA?

Comment: @SQB, yes, in the USA.

Answer (score 9):

Could this be [*The Scorpion with Two Tails*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Scorpion_with_Two_Tails) (AKA *Assassinio al cimitero etrusco)* from 1982?

You can see the catacomb head twisting scene here:

Comment: No, it wasn't violent and it was a young man. I would have recognized John Saxon immediately because of Enter the Dragon.

Answer (score 8):

I found the answer. The movie is [Antichrist](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0071150/) (1974).  See [this description](https://mondoexploito.com/?p=8756) that includes the following picture:

[image: A body lies on the ground in a face-down position (the back and back of the arms and hands are visible) but the head is turned to be facing upwards]

This is the picture I remember most from the movie.

Comment: Hi, welcome (back) to SF&F.  You appear to have created a different account than the on you posted your question with.  You should [merge your accounts](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) so you can accept this answer to mark it as correct.